# Should I use a lock in the following scenario

Tags: c#, .net, thread-safety

I had designed a Stack wrapper class. My confusion is, should I be using `lock` while popping  or pushing objects to the stack variable "`ParameterStack`". Please let me know, whether this class is thread safe or not.

```
public static class StackManager
{
    private static Stack ParameterStack = new Stack();

    public static T Pop<T>()
    {
        T RawObject;
        T Result = default(T);

        lock (ParameterStack)
        {
            RawObject = (T)ParameterStack.Pop();
        }

        if (RawObject != null && RawObject is T)
            Result = (T)RawObject;

        return (T)Result;
    }

    public static void Push<T>(T Data)
    {
        lock (ParameterStack)
        {
            ParameterStack.Push(Data);
        }
    }
}
```

I had created this StackManager class for learning purpose.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks OK. There is a (rather theoretical) argument that locking on `ParameterStack` itself is not totally safe because you don't own the code. Suppose somewhere inside the Stack does a `lock(this)` , you could deadlock.

```
public static class StackManager
{
    private static Stack parameterStack = new Stack();
    private static object stackLock = new object();

    // now use lock(stackLock) instead of lock(ParameterStack)

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `ConcurrentStack` in your case.
If you are not able to use `ConcurrentStack` - you can use `Stack.Synchronized()` method:

```
Stack mySynchronizedStack = Stack.Synchronized(myStack);
```

But even if you use `Synchronized()` method enumerations still not thread safe, you should use a lock to enumerate your stack.

```
Stack myStack = new Stack();
lock (myStack.SyncRoot)
{
    foreach (var element in myStack)
    {
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, but the generic version of `Stack` do not have a `Synchonization()` method.
So, you code should be:

```
public static class StackManager
{
    private static Stack ParameterStack;

    static StackManager()
    {
        ParameterStack = Stack.Synchronized(new Stack());
    }

    public static T Pop<T>()
    {
        object RawObject = ParameterStack.Pop();

        return RawObject is T ? (T)RawObject : default(T);
    }

    public static void Push<T>(T Data)
    {
        ParameterStack.Push(Data);
    }
}
```

You also should use `object` type for `RawObject` if you want to check the type. In your code you'll get an exception if you try to `Pop` object of different type.

Comment: Yes, but that requires Fx4, and wouldn't fulfill the 'learning purposes'

Comment: Thanks for the updated code snippet, as mentioned I will be definitely going for ConcurrentStack while moving to .NET Framework 4.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should. Stack is not synchronized by default in C#.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's thread safe. As long as any use of the internal stack is within a lock it will be safe to use with multiple threads.

You could use a `Stack<T>` to avoid all the casting by the way. Or as oxilumin says use ConcurrentStack if you aren't just trying to learn how to make something threadsafe.

Comment: "You could use a Stack<T>" - I think this stack is used to hold multiple types. Look at the name.

Comment: Good point. I probably shouldn't go answering questions before my morning coffee ;)

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware of the ConcurrentStack class? it is an efficient threadsafe implementation using lock-free